# Jquery Text Slider Loop

Tags: jquery

I have been trying to create a text slider, where it fades and slides in and then fades and slides out. Then the next element comes and does the same thing.

Manage to come up with this.

http://jsfiddle.net/3JKkj/6/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#heading1').css({opacity: 0}).animate({opacity: 1.0,left: "50px"}, 1000);    
     $('#heading1').css({opacity: 0}).delay(5000).animate({opacity: 0,left: "-50px"}, 1000);

     $('#heading2').css({opacity: 0}).delay(7000).animate({opacity: 1.0,left: "50px"}, 1000);
     $('#heading2').css({opacity: 0}).delay(5000).animate({opacity: 0,left: "-50px"}, 1000);

     $('#heading3').css({opacity: 0}).delay(14000).animate({opacity: 1.0,left: "50px"}, 1000);
     $('#heading3').css({opacity: 0}).delay(5000).animate({opacity: 0,left: "-50px"}, 1000);

     $('#heading4').css({opacity: 0}).delay(21000).animate({opacity: 1.0,left: "50px"}, 1000);
    $('#headings4').css({opacity: 0}).delay(5000).animate({opacity: 0,left: "-50px"}, 1000);

})
```

Seems a bit trivial having those delays in there? Is there a more effective way and how can i loop this so it is constantly looping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the best solution, but it will get you started on the right track.

http://jsfiddle.net/3JKkj/20/

```
var heading_cur=0;//current header
function showHeading(){
    $('#heading'+(heading_cur+1)).css({opacity: 0}).animate({opacity: 1.0,left: "50px"}, 1000);
    setTimeout(hideHeading, 5000);//hide it in 5 seconds
}
function hideHeading(){
    $('#heading'+(heading_cur+1)).css({opacity: 1}).animate({opacity: 0,left: "-50px"}, 1000
        ,function(){
            showHeading();//show the next when this has completed
        });
    heading_cur=(heading_cur+1)%4;
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    showHeading();//start the loop
})
```

CSS

```
#heading1,#heading2,#heading3,#heading4{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    opacity:0;/* Initial state */
}
```

Comment: This is what i wanted. ty. What does the %4 do? not had a chance to play around with it yet

Comment: it's the modulus operator. It returns the remainder from a division. It effectively resets the counter to 0 when the 4th header has been displayed.

Comment: I understand. I'd like to know why this isent the best solution. Looking at the solution above this post. This one in comparison seems more concise. I've noticed after putting this into practise and doing the same to another set of elements. So having headings slide out to the left and images slide out to the right. They do not always stay in sync. Despite the timings and number of elements being exactly the same.

Comment: Would be best, IMO, to move all this out of the global scope and into a single Object; move the headers into a containing DIV which will allow for more abstract CSS and better control over the positions. I would have to see the code to tell you why they are not synchronized. I assume you are using two timers. I would consolidate the animations to the two functions and only use one timer. That way the animations always starts at the same time.

Comment: The timeouts won't necessarily fire at the same time. they could easily become a few milliseconds off. Animations that should fire together need to be in the same function so that, at the very minimum, they start at the same time.

Comment: Yea i tried incorporate two different animations into 2 function, like this http://jsfiddle.net/3JKkj/46/ but it causes some problems.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30361/discussion-between-knyri-and-khan)