# Javascript text slider fadeout

Tags: javascript, jquery

i got some script from question [Jquery Text Slider Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16658403/jquery-text-slider-loop)

then i configure it myself ,this myscript

```
    function showHeading(){
        $('#ik'+(heading_cur+1)).css({'opacity' : '0','display' : 'block'}).animate({opacity: 1.0,left: '25px'}, 1000);
        setTimeout(hideHeading, 5000);
        }

 function hideHeading(){
        $('#ik'+(heading_cur+1)).css({'opacity' : '1','display' : 'none'}).animate({opacity: 0,left: '0px'}, 1000,function(){showHeading();});

        heading_cur=(heading_cur+1)%$jIk;
        }
```

i add `display:none` in hideHeading function but i want it disappear with transiton

Answer (score 0):

Add it in the `call back`

```
function hideHeading(){
        $('#ik'+(heading_cur+1))
          .css({'opacity' : '1'})
          .animate({opacity: 0,left: '0px'}, 1000
          ,function(){ $(this).hide(); showHeading();});

        heading_cur=(heading_cur+1)%$jIk;
        }
```

Then you can use `.show()` and `.hide()` instead of using `display` properties.